# PKCS7 - How do I know if the last byte is a pad or not?

Tags: cryptography, pkcs#7

Assuming I have blocks of 8 and I'm using PKCS7 for padding

a padded message would look like this

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 02 02
```

Where 02 02 is the padding

But what if I have a message that looks like this:

```
00 01 02 03 04 05 06 01
```

How can I determine if the last byte (01) is part of the actual message, or a padding of length 1?

Comment: [PKCS#7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)#PKCS#5_and_PKCS#7): _...If the length of the original data is an integer multiple of the block size B, then an extra block of bytes with value B is added. This is necessary so the deciphering algorithm can determine with certainty whether the last byte of the last block is a pad byte indicating the number of padding bytes added or part of the plaintext message..._

Comment: The last byte is *always* a pad byte, because plaintext is *always* padded.

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk For PKCS#7 compatible padding anway. Decard, I've created an answer for you [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/80481/1172). For cryptographic questions that don't include coding you're welcome at our cryptography site (but check for dupes first).

Comment: @PresidentJamesMoveonPolk well yes, but only if you encrypt plain text - if you encrypt arbitrary bytes.. Topaco's answer does the trick

Comment: Topaco's answer and my answer are the same. I was merely emphasizing his point. And plaintext is what you call the data you encrypt, whether it's ASCII text or arbitrary bytes.